# Unsuccessful update of video.js

Tags: 7

New user here so this could be a dumb question, but I've searched the web and can't find the answer.

In my Status Report I have this error mentioned:

```
Video.js    Unsupported Video.js version 3.2.0
The installed version of the Video.js library is not supported. This version of the Video.js module only supports Video.js version 4. Download Video.js version 4 and extract it into the sites/all/libraries/video-js directory or download Video.js module version 7.x-2.x to use Video.js 3.
```

So I did what it said, downloaded Video.js 4.9.1 and replaced the files in `sites/all/libraries/video-js`. But it doesn't make any difference, the same error message remains. Any ideas why?

Comment: What module are you using that uses video.js ? Sorry, I just read the question again. video.js module

Comment: It may be related to this open issue. https://www.drupal.org/node/2192515